# ionic network plugin status err

Tags: angular, networking, ionic3

I want to be able to update an ionic page based on the network status. the function is being called but the plug network status err in mobile go deep sleep and wake up . network is online before mobile phone go deep sleep , when mobile deep sleep then network should be disconnected ,when mobile wakeup  then network should be connected .

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient,
private platform: Platform,
private network:Network,
private file: File) {
console.log('Hello CommonSdkProvider Provider');
this.disconnected =false;
 platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.

    this.file.createFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory,"11122333.txt",true).then((selfmdule)=>{
      var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selfmdule));
      console.log("****ok****");
      console.log(result);
      this.canWritefile =true;
      this.getNetWorkConnected();
    }).catch((err)=>{

      var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(err));
      console.log("****fail****");
      console.log(result);
      this.canWritefile =false;
    })


});

}

getNetWorkConnected(){
let iWriteOptions:IWriteOptions
iWriteOptions={replace:false,append:true}
if(this.isMobile()){
let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() =>   {
console.log('****network was disconnected! *****');
this.disconnected =true;
this.vNetWorkDescriptUnConected = disconnectSubscription;
if(this.canWritefile){
        this.file.writeFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory,"11122333.txt","network was disconnected\r\n",iWriteOptions)
    }
  });

  // stop disconnect watch
  //disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();


  // watch network for a connection
  let connectChangeSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('******network connected!*****');
    this.disconnected =false;
    this.vNetWorkDescriptConected = connectChangeSubscription;
     if(this.canWritefile){
      this.file.writeFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory,"11122333.txt","network connected\r\n",iWriteOptions);

    }
  });

    let connectSubscription = this.network.onchange().subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    this.disconnected =false;
    this.vNetWorkChangeDescriptConected = connectSubscription;
     if(this.canWritefile){
      this.file.writeFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory,"11122333.txt","network change\r\n",iWriteOptions)
     }
    });
}
isMobile(): boolean {
    return this.platform.is('mobile') && !this.platform.is('mobileweb');
}
```

result: 
when mobile deep sleep then network should be disconnected ,when mobile wakeup  network  still disconnected .  If we Manually trigger network online and off line . status is correct.  But network status err when  mobile  in deep sleep . how i can get correct result. 
thank you !